# Robust and complete expansion or RRULE in python

Tags: python, python-dateutil, rrule

Using dateutil.rrulestr, I manage to expand some recurrences, for example one that looks like:

```
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20100930T183000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20100930T193000
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20101005T163000Z
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
...
```

using for example:

```
my_rrule.between(datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 2, 11, 00, tzinfo=pytz.utc),
                 datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 9, 11, 00, tzinfo=pytz.utc)))
```

However, this gives me only the start datetimes for the events, not the end datetimes.
Is there a way to get the end times too ? (cleaner than computing the start-end delta myself and applying it to every start time).

Also, some recurrences can be for all-day events and be in the form:

```
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20120225
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20120226
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SA
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
...
```

If I try to expand this one with the same between() call, I get an error:

```
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

Is there some query that would work for any kind of recurrence (ideally returning date or datetime values, depending on the case) ?

Answer (score 1):

`dateutil.rrule` and friends have no concept of durations: they are repeating rules of instants in time.

My solution was to replace `rruleset` with a custom class, that also accepts a duration (or provides a default one).

Then, I can generate occurrences, and tack onto each occurrence it's duration, to determine the interval.